# FileStreamResult on img tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC controller returning FileStreamresult as Image/png like below in my ajax callback function.And same need to be assigned to a `<img src="Image here!!"/>`. Please let me know how can i do this.

```
fileResult=new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(byte), "image/png");
```

Comment: by setting the `src` of your `img` to the address of the MVC action that returns `image/png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a controller and action to return the `FileStreamResult`:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Avatar() 
  {
      return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(byte), "image/png");
  }
}
```

And in your `img` tag you can point to that controller:

```
<img src="/image/avatar"/>
```